# Not able to instanciate class

Tags: oop, arduino, esp32, arduino-c++

I am a beginner in C++. So please bear with me:

I try to write code for a temperature sensor which should post values to an API.

I am not able to instantiate my class `ApiClient`.
I always get these errors:

- IDE: call of an object of a class type without appropriate operator() or conversion functions to pointer-to-function type
- IDE: no instance of overloaded function "ApiClient::ApiClient" matches the specified type
- COMPILER: no match for call to '(ApiClient) (String&)'

My code looks like this (slightly slimmed for easier reading):

**main.cpp**

```
#include <ApiClient.h>
ApiClient api;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  String apiUrl = "https://myapi.com/api";
  api(apiUrl); // ERROR: raises call of an object of a class type without appropriate operator() or conversion functions to pointer-to-function type

}

void loop()
{

  String temp = "49";
  api.sendValue("temperature", temp);
}
```

**ApiClient.h**

```
#ifndef WebClient_h
#define WebClient_h

#include <Arduino.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <esp_wps.h>
#include <HTTPClient.h>

class ApiClient
{
public:
  ApiClient(); // this is only added for testing
  ApiClient(String apiUrl); // it should always instanciate with url
  void sendValue(String key, String value);
  String _apiUrl;
private:
};

#endif
```

**ApiClient.cpp**

```
#include <ApiClient.h>

String _apiUrl;

HTTPClient http;

ApiClient::ApiClient(String apiUrl) // IDE says: "no instance of overloaded function "ApiClient::ApiClient" matches the specified type"
{
  this->_apiUrl = apiUrl;
  // some stuff to establish a connection
}
```

Comment: You have a global variable, it gets constructed before `main`, but you want to construct it from `main` arguments. See the issue? You have a design issue, as `api` is used in `loop`. Rewrite everything, start from responsibilities and work out an object hierarchy.

Comment: Why do you need an unitialized ApiClient for testing ?  The error comes from the presence of the defauit constructor.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher, I am still learning (noob) with C++. So I only tried to refactor this example (https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/WiFi/examples/WPS/WPS.ino) to keep my main.cpp lean. @michaël-roy. I thought `ApiClient api;` only declares the api, while `ApiClient api(apiEndpoint);` instantiate it. So declaring it globally to be able to use it in main (initialize) and call `api.sendvalue(k,v)` in the loop whenever I need it. But it seems that I am at the very first beginning of understanding C.

Comment: If you are learning C++, don't try something that complicated with events and all that stuff. Go for something simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to call a constructor on an already constructed object.

This line fails:

```
api(apiUrl);
```

The call you are attempting fails because the compiler is looking for one of these functions:

```
return_type APIClient::operator()(const String&);
return_type APIClient::operator()(String); 
return_type APIClient::operator()(String&);
```

Your statement should be a declaration if you want your constructor to be called.

```
ApiClient api(apiUrl);
// or better in c++11:
APIClient api{ apiUrl };
```

Alternatively, you could create an initializer in ApiClient, that takes a single String as a parameter, something like this:

```
class ApiClient
{
public:
    ApiClient() { ...}
    ApiClient(const String& s) { Initialize(s); }
    Initialize(const String& s) { do the work }

    ...
};
```

Be careful when providing both one-step and two steps initialization APIs in your classes.  You'll need a proper reset function to avoid mix-ups when reinitializing with a new string.